# Accessing HTTPS web page from webbrowser using self signed certificate

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am new to windows phone. I am developing a web-app and the test environment uses a self signed HTTPS certificate. Is there any way of accessing the test environment pages from an internal `WebBrowser` in my page?
I tried loading the URL but I always get the `NavigationFailed` event, with no details on the error. If I load a normal HTTP url, it works.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the certificate on your phone. Email the certificate to yourself, and then open that email on the phone.